# HTDS configuration for the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I have configured the Hosted Transparent Decision Services (HTDS) web application for ODM. Can I apply similar configuration changes when using the Business Rules service on Bluemix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Business Rules service on Bluemix does use HTDS to execute rules, however it is not possible to configure the HTDS web application for the service.